# jQuery Autocomplete Result Box Being Covered By Other Elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, z-index, jquery-autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete box with relatively and absolutely placed items below it.  When the results box opens up, the result box is covered by the elements below it.  The `z-index` for the items below the drop down box are less than 10.

I can't figure out the name of the result box or result items to set a higher z-index.

Something like

```
#autocomplete_results{
    z-index: 20
}
```

my html:

```
<div class="normal"><input id="college" class="inputField" type="text" name="college" placeholder="College Name" data-autocomplete-source="<%= colleges_accounts_url %>"></div>
```

coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#college").autocomplete
    source: $("#college").data('autocomplete-source'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using absolutely positioned elements you need to set the z-index of the parent element, in this case if you are using jQuery UI, it is the parent of .ui-autocomplete

You then need to set the elements you want underneath to z-index:-1 to ensure they appear underneath the autocomplete menu

Comment: Updated with my html.  What is the "parent of .ui-autocomplete"?

Comment: nvm, got it, thanks.  `#college` in case anyone else gets stuck

Comment: the parent is whatever you put the autocomplete element inside (so its #college for you but not for someone else)...glad it worked!